# complex validation on object update?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1, mysql2

I have a model "WorkDetail" and db-attrs related to problem are 'name', 'status' and 'approved_status' with datatype all integer and the model class definition is as:-

```
class WorkDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum name: [:smartcheck, :install, :verify]
  enum status: [:pending, :inprogress, :complete]

  belongs_to :work_order
  has_many :cabinets

  after_save :work_order_status_update

  private

  def work_order_status_update
    work_detail_count = self.work_order.work_details.count
    status_array = self.work_order.work_details.where(status: 2).count
    if status_array == work_detail_count
      if work_detail_count == 0
        self.work_order.update({status: "pending"})
      else
        self.work_order.update({status: "complete"})
      end
    else
      self.work_order.update({status: "inprogress"})
    end
  end
end
```

Now, I would like  to add custom validation to be applied for below problem :-

1. validation should only apply for update process.
2. If object's `name == "smartcheck"` and `status == "complete"` then only the `approved_status` boolean attribute should be `updated` to `true` (the
   default is false on migration), else should give error if not
   smartchecked and the status is not complete on trying to update
   approved_status attr.

Hoping the question makes sense and Thanks !!! in advance guys, Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Validation should only apply for update process

```
 after_save :work_order_status_update,  :on => :update
```

> 2) If object's name == "smartcheck" and status == "complete" then only
>   the approved_status boolean attribute should be updated to true (the
>   default is false on migration), else should give error if not
>   smartchecked and the status is not complete on trying to update
>   approved_status attr.

```
def test_status_and_name
  if self.name == "smartcheck" and self.status == "complete"
    self.update_attributes(approved_status: true)
  else
    errors[:base] << "smartchecked and the status is not complete on trying to update approved_status attr."
  end
end
```